# Wrong name for my user folder in File Explorer but shows OK in command line

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

My user folder in File explorer is replaced with the name `Dokument`,
but I can see my user folder from the command line:

[image: File Explorer vs. command line]

I can access the folder if I type `C:\Users\mittm\` directly in File Explorer bar.

The information in the folder `Dokument` is the same I see when I navigate to `C:\Users\mittm\`:

`dir /a` in c:\Users

[image: File Explorer vs command line]

How can I fix my username in File Explorer?

Comment: What do you get if you type `dir /a` ?

Comment: Try deleting or renaming the `desktop.ini` file in `mittm`.

Comment: @SpiderPig Where do u want me to do that? In c:\Users

Comment: run `dir /a` in `c:\users` and update your screenshot with that. Also rename `c:\users\mittm\desktop.ini` to something else. That should force the explorer to display the correct name.

Comment: @SpiderPig updated with screenshot dir /a

Comment: If you can't find `desktop.ini`, change your explorer settings to make it show all files, even system files.